# What design is best for data transformation?

Tags: performance, database-design

My company's database makes available data to a lot of external applications. So I need to transform the same data to a lot of *dynamic* views. I can see that a former database developer had implemented many long chains of view-function-procedure call sequences to do transformation more common to all external applications. I think, this architecture and so long requests (stored proc calls a function, then function calls some view and this view based on other one and so on) are a performance problem, at least query optimizer does not resolve these issues (please confirm my guesses).

Is it a good approach? Does it cause degradation of performance? If yes, how can I reimplement objects of the database.

At this moment I see these steps to do this:

- analysis of source data structure (own data)
- analysis of all external systems (what formats does database have to provide for)
- separate views, functions, stored procs for every external subsystems (I have to avoid long chains, common to many subsystems DB objects, if it is a cause of problem)

Comment: I can tell you that views calling other views will be a performance problem in SQL Server as they have to fully materialize the lower views and they can't be indexed. Your problem is your designer thinnks like an OOP programmer and that is a very ineffective way to design databases and acces to the data.

Comment: @HLGEM it makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered building a [**datamart**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mart) instead? Maybe it's what your colleague already did?

It highly depends on your specific case, but I understand you can't describe your whole business in your question.

If you are serious about that, I recommend you this great book which not only describe how to do it, but explain deeply all the problems you could encounter in such situations.

[The Data Warehouse Toolkit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471200247)

[image]

Check out others [Ralph Kimball books](http://www.amazon.com/Ralph-Kimball/e/B000AP5ULY/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_1) as well.

Comment: +1 to the datamart concept and I think @igor has already identified the starting points for that, analysing your internal existing data structure and its relationships vs what external entities require is a good segregation to have.

Answer (score 1):

I think the former employee has been trying to create a logical view on the data that is separate from the physical representation.

When clients are attached to Views and/or stored procedures you have some room to refactor the physical representation without the clients requiring any modifications.

Of course this logical layer adds some indirection and may cost extra processing time. However this may still be worthwhile from a maintainability viewpoint though.
Being able to juggle with tables and relationships below this logical layer can also help when dealing with performance issues.

Sometimes being slower is not necessarily a problem, is it still fast enough?